# JavaScript Date Comparison Not Evaluating Correctly

Tags: javascript

This expression is evaluating to true. Why?

```
if ($scope.state.dateStart < $scope.state.previousStart || $scope.state.dateEnd > $scope.state.previousEnd) {
```

When debugging, I can see that the values are the same, so the expression shouldn't be true:

[image]

**Edit: At some point, the previous values are set like this:**

```
$scope.state.previousStart = new Date($scope.state.dateStart);
$scope.state.previousEnd = new Date($scope.state.dateEnd);
```

**Edit: This is the angular factory, showing how the values are initially defined.**

```
app.factory('historyRepository', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var state = {
        allBatches: [],
        filteredBatches: [],
        selectedBatch: null,
        allStatuses: [],
        dateStart: new Date(),
        dateEnd: new Date(),
        previousStart: new Date(),
        previousEnd: new Date()
    }

    // Set initial start and end date times
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7); // 7 days ago
    state.dateStart = new Date(date);
    state.previousStart = new Date(date);
    state.dateEnd.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // Use ending of end date. (hour,min,sec,millisec)
    state.previousEnd.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // Use ending of end date. (hour,min,sec,millisec)

    return state;
}]);
```

Comment: Don't paste image, but only text, thanks

Comment: `dateStart` is defined first, since you didn't pass anything to the constructor (of `date) it uses the current time, therefore it is older.

Comment: where are `dateEnd` and `previousEnd` defined?

Comment: Gilles: I can't show the debug values without pasting an image. Pamblam: That would be true if I used those initial values, but they're changed later. Per the screenshot, you can see they have the same time.

Comment: @charlietfl I edited my post to show that.

Comment: I edited my post one more time. I don't have a separate example at the moment. I can possibly do a fiddle later tonight.

Comment: I got it. You can see it solved via my answer, below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my end dates; specifically, the milliseconds. When setting a date using an existing date, the milliseconds aren't set. Need to set milliseconds to make dates equal.

```
$scope.state.previousEnd = new Date($scope.state.dateEnd);
$scope.state.previousEnd.setMilliseconds(999);
// Now previousEnd and dateEnd are the same.
```

I was able to see that the dates weren't the same by doing this:

```
// Show milliseconds since January 1, 1970
console.log('dateEnd', $scope.state.dateEnd.getTime());
console.log('previousEnd', $scope.state.previousEnd.getTime());
```

And here is the output:

> ```
>     dateEnd 1476331199999
> previousEnd 1476331199000
> ```